# Is there any way in Java to enforce a minimum window size?

Tags: java, swing, resize, jframe, minimum

Is there any way in Java to enforce a minimum window size?

The last article I can find is from 1999, and has some complicated code to mimic the behaviour...
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/1999-10/03-qa-window.html

Surely there is a simple method that can be used?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I usually set the minimum size of a window by setting the minimum sizes of the [`JComponents`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) inside of the window.

```
jcomponent.setMinimumSize(Dimension d);
```

That line of code will limit a component's minimum size.

You can also call `setMinimumSize()` on the `JFrame` directly to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: Ah, that worked. Strange that all my googling didn't turn that up. Thank you!